# Plugin for changing declaration to be java collection interfaces rather than specific implementation

Tags: java, collections, eclipse-plugin

I would like to know whether there are any plugins available to change the Declarations into Java collection Interfaces such as "List" rather than specific implementation classes such as "LinkedList". This is because I need to change for a very huge number of files!!!
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `List list = (List) LinkedList` ? [Read this](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/)

Comment: The search and replace functionality in Eclipse is quite powerful and accepts  regular expressions with capture groups. You should be able to use that if you use a capture group for the list name.

Comment: I agree with Nick. I use Eclipse refactoring daily and it's very powerful.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. My question is, like sonarqube which finds the issues for Declarations, are there any plugins to clear the issues?
Which would change all occurance of tightly coupled Class reference and instance into loosely coupled Interface and instance.
Like...

List list = new ArrayList();

instead of...

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

Comment: I don't think there's a specific plugin to do this, but the search/replace should be an adequate alternative. I'll try and put an example together.

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace with regular expressions should do this for you. Use the Search->File menu option and set the file name pattern to `*.java`. The containing text can be something like:

```
ArrayList (\w+) \=
```

Click the `Replace` button and in the next dialog use:

```
List $1 =
```

That will replace `ArrayList` with `List` but maintain the field name. You would have to do the same for other collection types, and possibly use another search and replace to add missing imports.

Comment: But Nick, That regex is not working and I am getting a response for the search as "0 matches in workspace". And I am having a huge number of class files to be edited that it would take a very long time to do it manually!

Comment: Make sure you've got the `Regular expression` box checked in the search dialog. You may need to adjust the search expression depending on how you have your code formatted.